# CSS align nav bar

Tags: html, css

[Link to current nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCxwV.png)

Currently the text is at the bottom, i want it in the middle so there is the same amount of space above and below the links???

What would be the correct css for this?

```css
body{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
 text-align:center;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
 outline:none;
 padding:10px;
 display:block;
 width:300px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border:1px solid #eee;
 margin:20px auto;
}

input[type="submit"]{
 padding:10px;
 color:#fff;
 background:#0098cb;
 width:320px;
 margin:20px auto;
 margin-top:0px;
 border:0px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover{
 background:#00b8eb;
}

.phone{
 border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
 padding:10px 0px;
 width:100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: right;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-right: 20px;
 float:right;
 background-color:#2c2c2f;
 color: #fff;
}

.header{
 border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
 padding:10px 0px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:left;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#logo {
 padding-left: 10px;
 align-content: left;
}

.header a{
 color:#333;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.header a.active {
 color: red;
}

.footer {
 border-top:1px solid #eee;
 font-size:50%;
  position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="phone"><a>Freephone: 0800 96 161</a></div>
<div class="header">
<img id="logo" src="images\logo.png" alt="logo">
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="products.html">Products</a></div>

 <h1></h1>

<div class="footer">
<p><b></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

//edited to add the full code for people to look at, this will probably be more useful

Comment: Padding BOTTOM just moves the line down?

Comment: can you provide a snippet to work with, i mean full HTML along with the CSS?

Comment: Would be great to post on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: EDITED to add full code

Comment: @LewisJUK The snippet seems to show that the nav contents are indeed in the middle, unlike the screenshot which you've appended. what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works fine

```css
<div class="header">
 <img id="logo" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/33/b8/69/33b869f90619e81763dbf1fccc896d8d.jpg" alt="logo">
 <a href="index.html">Home</a>
 <a href="products.html">Products</a>
</div>
```

```html
header{
    display: flex;
}
header a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the line height of the list items to the same height fo the header:

```
.header{
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px; /* This same as */
}

.header a{
    color:#333;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    line-height: 40px; /* This */
}
```

```css
body{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
 text-align:center;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
 outline:none;
 padding:10px;
 display:block;
 width:300px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border:1px solid #eee;
 margin:20px auto;
}

input[type="submit"]{
 padding:10px;
 color:#fff;
 background:#0098cb;
 width:320px;
 margin:20px auto;
 margin-top:0px;
 border:0px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover{
 background:#00b8eb;
}

.phone{
 border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
 padding:10px 0px;
 width:100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: right;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-right: 20px;
 float:right;
 background-color:#2c2c2f;
 color: #fff;
}

.header{
 border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
 width:100%;
 text-align:left;
 overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px; /* This same as */
}

#logo {
 padding-left: 10px;
 align-content: left;
}

.header a{
 color:#333;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: 20px;
    line-height: 40px; /* This */
}

.header a.active {
 color: red;
}

.footer {
 border-top:1px solid #eee;
 font-size:50%;
  position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="phone"><a>Freephone: 0800 96 161</a></div>
<div class="header">
<img id="logo" src="images\logo.png" alt="logo">
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="products.html">Products</a></div>

 <h1></h1>

<div class="footer">
<p><b></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```